# How to avoid "can be undefined" error in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple code to input a positive integer in the most accurate way possible. I mention that I am very new to the language.

Here is my code :

```
while number != None:
    try:
        while True:
            number = int(input("Donnez la longueur de votre liste: "))
            if number > 0:
                break
    except TypeError:
        print("Tu doit donner un nombre entier")
```

The warning I get is `number can be Undefined` I am not aware of what is the specific situation where `number is undefined` as the while loop breaks only when number is not None ( means defined according to me ). I’m so grateful for your help. It is a challenging time but you would make it easier.

Comment: If you aren't initializing `number` before the loop starts, then it *is* undefined for the first time the condition is evaluated. If you are initializing it, then nothing in this code *undefines* it, so I don't know where that warning would be coming from.

Comment: Remember that the `while` condition gets evaluated once BEFORE the loop ever runs.  If you have not set `number = ...something...` before entering the loop, than it is undefined when it first checks `while number != None:`.

Comment: A variable being undefined is NOT the same as a variable being equal to None.

Comment: Hey, indeed it is not initialized it is supposed to be inputted by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sidestep any warnings with a more idiomatic loop:

```
while True:
    number = input("Donnez la longueur de votre liste: ")
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("Tu doit donner un nombre entier")
        continue
    
    if number > 0:
        break
```

Comment: I often wonder why people choose that route instead of using `if not number.isdigit():`.  Exceptions are somewhat expensive, and the code doesn't read smoothly.

Comment: Catching an exception is expensive; a `try` block that doesn't raise an exception is virtually zero-cost. In this case, if there *is* an exception, the next thing that happens is the program blocks waiting for more input, which dwarfs the cost of raising and catching the exception anyway.

Comment: Plus, `'-3'` is a number that `number.isdigit()` would reject, and you probably want to call `int` anyway once you have verified (redundantly) that `int` won't raise an exception.

Comment: Yes it might be a good solution, I am just newly learned how exceptions work that's why I am using it.

Comment: The key part is using an "infinite" loop with an explicit break statement, rather requiring `number` be defined before the loop starts.

Comment: @TimRoberts, `str.isdigit()` will be True for number of non-ascii digits, which will raise error with `int()`. It is mentioned in the docs - _This covers digits which cannot be used to form numbers in base 10, like the Kharosthi numbers._